# Why iam getting Ja.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, exception, stack-overflow

Why iam getting java.`enter code here`lang.StackOverflowError exception in below program

```
public class Image {

  Image i=new Image();

  public Image() {
  }


  private byte[] image_array;
  private String image_name;
  private long id;
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        Image ii=new Image();
   }  
}
```

Comment: And hint: learn about java naming conventions. A) dont use under_scores except for constants B) use names that *mean* something. `Image i` ... means nothing. `ii` is even worse.

Comment: And sorry, but who is upvoting a question that is a super obvious duplicate?

Comment: I think this question isn't quite as obvious because the constructor is actually empty and then there is an instance field with a call to that constructor. So the explanation would require referring to JLS and how instance fields are initialized.

Comment: that makes it quite obvious if you know the basic of a java class instanciation

Comment: @jhamon, but the duplicate question doesn't really address that.

Answer (score 4):

Because when the line  `Image ii=new Image();` gets executed inside `main` it creates instance of `Image` and inside which you've written line `Image i=new Image();`

Which means you keep creating new `Image` instances repeatedly.

Just keep it like `Image i;` and initialize it on need basis.

Comment: What triggers the recursion when the constructor is empty? Shouldn't the call stack end there?

Comment: I am asking for a better explanation about what is happening; _why_ does it create instances repeatedly and what exactly causes the endless recursion? There isn't an explicit recursive call anywhere in the code.

Comment: @MickMnemonic It's because `Image i=new Image();` is inside class `Image` and its an instance variable. An instance variable is initialized(if not initialized explicitly it defaults to null(for objects)) when an instance of that class is created. Thought it's obvious to understand ;-)

Comment: I was looking for an explanation that referred to the [relevant  part of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) where the execution order of instance variable initializers w.r.t. the constructor is specified.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you instantiate an object of class `Image`, it is started to be created. Along this process, it receives a field `i` of type `Image`, which is initialized with a new object of class `Image`. This one gets initialized again, and so on.

Just remove that line `Image i=new Image();`.